# Нажатие на элемент горизонтального RecycledView, который внутри вертикального RecycledView

Tags: android, kotlin

Как обработать нажатие на элемент горизонтального RecycledView, который внутри вертикального RecycledView

внутренний адаптер

```
    class MovieAdapter(private val list: List<Movie>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieHolder>() {
        interface OnStateClickListener {
            fun onStateClick(movie: Movie, position: Int)
        }
    
        private val onClickListener: OnStateClickListener? = null
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            return MovieHolder(inflater, parent)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieHolder, position: Int) {
            val movie: Movie = list[position]
            holder.bind(movie)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
                onClickListener!!.onStateClick(
                    movie,
                    position
                )
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size
```

Внешний адаптер

```
    class OutAdapter (private val itemList: List<FilmGenre>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<OutHolder>() {
        private val viewPool = RecycledViewPool()
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OutHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            return OutHolder(inflater, parent,)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(ganreViewHolder: OutHolder, position: Int) {
            val itemHolder = itemList[position]
    
            ganreViewHolder.bindGanre(itemHolder)
    
            ganreViewHolder.movieItem.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
    
    
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return itemList.size
        }
```

Comment: у вас нажатие не срабатывает, или в чем проблема?

Comment: нужно действие перенести в главную активити, для вызова фрагмента или активити

Comment: какое действие? у вас два нажатия, ничего непонятно